# How much emphasis is given on past research publications while evaluating postdoctoral grant proposals?

Tags: postdocs, funding, japan

I am writing a project proposal for the JSPS postdoctoral fellowship in Japan. In my PhD I had 3 first author research papers with average impact factors (betwen 2.5 and 5.5) in my field (heterogeneous catalysis). I had some co-authored papers in slightly better journals.

My question is- how much emphasis is given to the strength of the proposal itself compared to the past publications? Can a good research proposal be undermined by average quality of research papers in the past?

Comment: Realistically I don’t think anyone really knows what JSPS values in applications, my experience and from talking to others is that it can be quite arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience